# Workspace Domain-wide Delegation with service account not working for one project, works for others

Tags: c#, google-cloud-platform, google-workspace, service-accounts

We have different projects on GCP we use them to access different Google APIs. Most of them for internal use only.

In this particular case, we have 2 projects, **both use Service Account and both are allowed on Workspace Domain-wide Delegation on the same scopes**. They are almost clones of each other.

I execute a simple request **with the same code** (`Spreadsheet.Get()`) with project 1 credentials it works. I execute the same request with project 2 credentials it doesn't work.

Since Workspace Domain-wide Delegation it's activated the spreadsheet its shared to my email and I connect to the API with my email too (works with project 1 so this is not the problem)  (impersonating a user)

The only difference it's that one project has OAuth Consent Screen on external (only 100 users cause we use it internally only, anyways..) and the other one it's internal but this has nothing to do with this right?

Where the problem could come from? Do I need to recreate the project that doesn't work?

Here is the error message :

> Client is unauthorized to retrieve access tokens using this method, or client not authorized for any of the scopes requested

*Edit to answer the comments but this code works depending on the service account we use*

**Generating the credentials:**

```
internal static ServiceCredential GetApiCredentialsFromJson(string jsonCredentialsPath, string mailToMimic)
        {
            string jsonCertificate = File.ReadAllText(jsonCredentialsPath);
            string privateKey = Regex.Match(jsonCertificate, @"(?<=""private_key"": "")(.*)(?="")").Value.Replace(@"\n", "");
            string accountEmail = Regex.Match(jsonCertificate, @"(?<=""client_email"": "")(.*)(?="")").Value;

            ServiceAccountCredential.Initializer credentials = new ServiceAccountCredential.Initializer(accountEmail)
            {
                Scopes = _scopes,
                User = mailToMimic
            }.FromPrivateKey(privateKey);

            return new ServiceAccountCredential(credentials);
        }
```

**Using the credentials:**

```
internal GoogleSheetService(ServiceCredential credentials)
    {
        SheetsService = new SheetsService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
        {
            HttpClientInitializer = credentials
        });
        SheetsService.HttpClient.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(100);
    }
```

**Client ID is allowed on the Drive, Ads and Spreadsheets scopes on the Workspace console.**

[image]

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: Are you using a service account to read/write on your sheet (have you shared the sheet to both of your service accounts)? or you are impersonating a user account with a service account?

Comment: @RonM Only impersonating a user accounts

Comment: Show the code that is using the service account to request an access token. Also, show the settings for Domain Wide Delegation for the service account in the Google Cloud console.

Comment: @johnhanley Done! But in my opinion, this is nothing to do with code.

Comment: Not the solution but you are using ancient code that was used to load P12 credentials. You can simplify your code using this `var credential = GoogleCredential.FromFile(sa_file).CreateScoped(scopes).CreateWithUser(user_email);`

Comment: Which scopes are you specifying?

Comment: 1) Display the contents of the problem service account. Extract the value of "client_id". 2) go to Google Workspace Admin Console -> Main Menu -> Security -> API Controls. Scroll down to Domain wide delegation. 3) Verify that the Client ID is listed with the scopes that you are using in your code.

Comment: Go to https://myaccount.google.com/permissions. Verify that you have granted access.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235702/discussion-between-borisd-and-john-hanley).

Comment: What are the results? If a question requires going to chat, the question needs to be updated with more information so that it can be answered.

Comment: No results @JohnHanley

Comment: No results for what? I provided a list of steps to verify. Edit your question with details of each step and the results.

Comment: Thank you @JohnHanley but as my questions says : `Client ID is allowed on the Drive, Ads and Spreadsheets scopes on the Workspace console.`

Comment: Yes, and you say that both service accounts are configured the same, yet one does not work.

Comment: 25/10/21 : same issue again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was simple, but we had to figure it out by ourselves.

The scopes you add in your app when you initialize the client need to be exactly the same scopes you added in the Google Admin wide-delegation page. *Even if your app or part of your app don't need them all.*

C# example:

```
        private static readonly string[] _scopes = { DriveService.Scope.Drive, SheetsService.Scope.Spreadsheets, SlidesService.Scope.Presentations };

        ServiceAccountCredential.Initializer credentials = new ServiceAccountCredential.Initializer(accountEmail)
        {
            Scopes = _scopes,
            User = mailToMimic
        }.FromPrivateKey(privateKey);

        return new ServiceAccountCredential(credentials);
```

Here my app only needs `SheetsService.Scope.Spreadsheets` but I had to add `DriveService.Scope.Drive` and `SlidesService.Scope.Presentations` because the same client its used for other apps that need them.